# How to test that an Observable does not emit in Angular Component which contains asynchronous logic

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, angular-test

Let's say I have an Angular Component which defines an Observable `myObs$` as one of its properties.

In one test, given certain conditions, I want to test that `myObs$` does not notify. In the logic there are some delays involved, so the test must be asynchronous.

I am using **Jasmine**.

So far I have been able to craft this solution:

```
it('async test', done => {
    let dataEmitted;
    myObs$
    .pipe(
      tap(data => dataEmitted = data),
    )
    .subscribe();
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (dataEmitted) {
        done.fail('should not emit');
      } else {
        done();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
```

But I am far from happy with it. I have to rely on `setTimeout` to perform the checks and call the `done` function.

Any suggestions on how to perform such tests properly? Synchronous solutions do not work since there is intrinsic asynchronicity in the logic.

Answer (score 24):

If it's asynchronous logic that based on **setTimeout/debounceTime and so forth**, you can use **fakeAsync()** function to test it, this function will **substitute** all these **asynchronous** operations with **synchronous** ones, so it will be possible to test your logic since it's synchronous. Also you can use **tick()** to skip VM turns (and it happens also synchronously!). Using this solution you will have nice and clean, fast and reliable unit tests.

### Code example

```
it('asynch test', fakeAsync(() => {
    let dataEmitted;
    myObs$.subscribe(data => dataEmitted = data);

    tick(1000);
    
    expect(dataEmitted).toBeUndefined();
}));
```

I suggest you also to check negative scenario, for example **tick(2000)** and check if it emits value. Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool one! thanks! the `skip` operator is quite fancy! I am wondering if it is interchangeable with `tick` that comes together with `fakeAsync`

Comment: You are right, I meant `tick` but wrote `skip`... I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Observable eventually completes, this can also be done with the conventional `it` function by using `done()`:

```
it(
  'async test',
  (done: DoneFn) => {
    let emitted = false;
    myObs$
    .subscribe({
      next: () => emitted = true;
      complete: () => {
        expect(emitted).toBeFalse();
        done();
      }
    });
  }
);
```